# subset data based on particular values in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to make a copy of file where a particular columns appears twice. I need both the entries but in a separate file.
Attached below is the code written but it is not able to read the list of ID on which it needs to subset

```
CREATE TABLE DUPLICATECLIENTID_AVOX AS SELECT * FROM nodup_avox_data_v1_nr WHERE CLIENT_ID =(select client_id from (select CLIENT_ID, count(CLIENT_ID) as clientcount 
from nodup_avox_data_v1_nr
group by CLIENT_ID
having count(CLIENT_ID) > 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try using IN() like so:

```
CREATE TABLE DUPLICATECLIENTID_AVOX AS
SELECT *
FROM nodup_avox_data_v1_nr
WHERE CLIENT_ID IN (
                     SELECT CLIENT_ID
                     FROM nodup_avox_data_v1_nr
                     GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
                     HAVING count(CLIENT_ID) > 1
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE DUPLICATECLIENTID_AVOX 
AS
SELECT *
  FROM nodup_avox_data_v1_nr
 WHERE CLIENT_ID IN (SELECT CLIENT_ID
                       FROM nodup_avox_data_v1_nr
                      GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
                     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
                    )
```

Pay attention I wrote `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` because you want columns that appear twice